# the form fields show up on top of the dropdown menus in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have javascript dropdown menus using jquery css and ul li. When they drop down over form fields,the fields show up on top of the menus in IE. Is there any way to fix this?

```
<ul id="Navigation">
<li> <a title='Home' href='/'>Home</a><span class='home'></span></li>
<li><a title='Article' href='/Article/'>Article</a>
<ul>
<li >
<a  href='/Article/ArticleSecondary/'>ArticleSecondary</a>
<ul>
<li ><a href='/Article/ArticleSecondary/'>ArticleSecondary</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
...
...
```

and js

```
$(function(){

    $("#Navigation li").hover(function(){

        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

    }, function(){

        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

    });

    $("#Navigation li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
   // $("#Navigation li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

});
```

Comment: try setting the z-index for the hover menus to be higher than the fields (if they have any at all, which they shouldnt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to deal with this is to put an iframe behind your drop down menus.  It will cover the form fields (presumably you are talking about select elements).

It's an ugly hack, but you do what you gotta do to make things work in IE.  The iframe approach is used by a lot of cross-site tools like Meebo and Apture and the like, where they don't know what will be behind their popups.  It also helps to make sure you cover flash items (youtube videos, etc).

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/08/09/how-to-put-a-div-over-a-select-in-ie.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just set the z-index of the menu in your css, or in javascript code :

```
$(function(){

    $("#Navigation li").hover(function(){

        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $(this).css( "z-index", "1000" )
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

    }, function(){

        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

    });

    $("#Navigation li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
   // $("#Navigation li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

});
```

Update :
For IE 6, try this:

```
<ul id="Navigation" style="position: relative; z-index: 3000">
```

Comment: Won't work in IE, select elements will bleed though unless you use the iframe hack.

Comment: For IE6 you can give the parent element a higher z-index value and it should work

Comment: it won't work, IE6 has specific issues with `<select>` elements...which some genius thought would be a great idea to borrow from windows forms controls.